# Whats the best way i can refactor this simple function? variable flow through all this functions mutating in that specific order

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

variable flow through all this functions mutating in that specific order, but i know this can be done in a better way. duration.sec is a variable from the parent function that  have to mutate its value with this setTime(s) function. All works well, but it is obvious that it can be improved, I always try to do better with this kind of flow

```
function setTime(s) {
    duration.sec = s;
    duration.sec = setYears(duration.sec);
    duration.sec = setDays(duration.sec);
    duration.sec = setHr(duration.sec);
    duration.sec = setMin(duration.sec);
  }
```

Comment: What do all the other functions do?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what are those functions the only thing that comes to mind is that you could do something like this to reuse the same logic in a couple of lines:

```js
function setTime(s) {
  [() => s, setYears, setDays, setHr, setMin].forEach((fn) => {
    duration.sec = fn(duration.sec);
  })
}
```